# Can AWS lambda listen to S3 createobject events when files are dropped manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

I have and s3 bucket and lambda function, this function has trigger which listens to s3 createobject events. somehow some are missed in s3, i am planning to drop them manually. Can my lambda function will get the events like before?

Also i will put files in different folders based on date. will i get different events on each file drop?

Comment: could you clarify the first question - what do mean by "some are missed in S3". Is S3 not firing the `createObject` events that your Lambda function is listening for?

Comment: my automation broke and few files were missed dropping. so i thought of manually adding them. It worked btw, lambda is getting events if i drop files manually.

Comment: Would you mind marking my answer as correct if it helped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the second question: Yes, every time a file is added to your bucket (assuming that the Lambda function is listening for changes on in all folders and not just a prefix), your lambda function will receive an `event` object that will contain information about that file.

Answer (score 0):

The `objectCreate:*` events fire whenever a file is updated in any way (except deletion) so yes, if you manually upload files to the bucket the event will fire *IFF* that file meets the prefix & suffix requirements.  The event payload data on a manually uploaded file doesn't appear to be different from one created via another process.